# Symfony: Get my associated records from manyToMany doctrine relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have four tables:

> games (venue_id and user_id)
>
> users
>
> venues (user_id)
>
> user_venue (user_id and venue_id)

and three entities: one for games, one for users and one for venues with a many to many relationship between the last two using the user_venue table.  These work fine.

However when I add a new game I want it to show only the venues that have a link with my `user_id` - I am unsure of how to do this. Currently it just pulls all of the venues out of the system.

```
$game=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Bundle:Game')->findOneById(1);
```

I'm looking at:

`$game->getVenues()` - this is passed to a form via the form builder so I don't actually run this command (i.e. `$builder->add('venues')`.

I know I haven't linked `user_id` in anywhere which is the reason I'm getting all venues, but where do I put this `user_id` in order to bring back only 'my' venues?

Comment: Isn't that what you need? http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Comment: This does look like what I want.  Thanks I'll give it a go.